# How to set Material-UI MenuItem width?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Menu with `Material-UI`, why is the whole screen width used? How can I limit to use only the text length needed space?

I tried to put div element around `MenuList` but it did not help.

```
class MainPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ThemeProvider, and override the MuiList-root width:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiList: {
      root:{
      width: 'fit-content'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And than in your component:

```
 <div>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <MenuList>
          <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </ThemeProvider>
</div>
```

Working CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-5sbjw?fontsize=14