# Const can not be defined in class in Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

Where should I put following line to get my component ready?

`const classes = useStyles();`

Try to use `Material-UI` `MenuList` component, but need to use in my existing `MainPage` code, what is slightly different from `Material-UI` code example.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742775/how-to-set-material-ui-menuitem-width

Answer (score 2):

Could you try to call it inside render lifecycle ?
If i'm not wrong, u can't create const directly inside class, the order should be class > function > const or let var
Or you can try to put it inside constructor

```
Constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.classes = useStyles()
}
```

Or you can do it like seanplwong suggest

Comment: Ahh render lifecycle... I'm forgetting the important React stuff and falsely blaming my limited knowledge of Javascript. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

constants are not supported at class level.

You have two options.

1. move the constants out of class and refer then.
2. Use static properties

This thread has some more information.
[Declaring static constants in ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647215/declaring-static-constants-in-es6-classes)

Answer (score 1):

I think for class properties, the syntax should be something like

```
class Foo {
  classes = useStyle();
}
```